DLT - how to get pipeline_id and update_id?
I need to insert pipeline_id and update_id in my Delta Live Table (DLT), the point being to know which pipeline created which row. How can I obtain this information?
I know you can get job_id and run_id from widgets but I don't know if these are the same things as pipeline_id and update_id.
I have a solution with event_hooks using Python but it looks wrong, I do not think it makes sense to listen for events in my DLT pipeline for this purpose.

What you are referring job_idand run_id are the details of the job runs in databricks and not from delta live tables.
If you go to delta live tables tab, in pipeline you can find pipeline_id and update_id .
Go to Delta Live Tables

And if you open the pipeline you will get update_id details in updates tab.

You can also get the full details about pipeline and update details using event log
You can create a table out of the event log file and query it to extract details.
Use any of the below code to create event log table.
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW event_log_raw AS SELECT * FROM delta.`<event-log-path>`;

Usually the event log path will the dbfs location you given while creating delta live table plus  /system/events/ something like below
dbfs:/dltTbl/system/events/
OR
Using pipeline id
SELECT * FROM event_log("<pipelineid>")

OR
You can create event log table with pipeline that owns the table
SELECT * FROM event_log(TABLE(my_catalog.my_schema.table1))

Next you can get latest update id by using below query
SELECT origin.update_id AS  id  FROM event_log_raw WHERE event_type =  'create_update'  ORDER  BY  timestamp  DESC  LIMIT  1;

Output:



id




76ef45b1-6426-4d4c-b9e5-307739b1dccb



Next, by removing LIMIT  1  you will get all update id in descending order.

Thanks. How do you ensure query is safe if multiple clusters and dlt pipelines are running concurrently?

Here you are not querying on the event log files directly. Creating a view or temp view so that it doesn't conflict with concurrent operations. Once the pipeline execution is completed then start querying because all the details will be available.

@JayashankarGS this assumes that the table exists, to call the table function. As I am using dlt.table decorator to create the table, how can I be sure that the table exists at that point in time?
